# Multiple "order by" in LINQ

Tags: linq, sql-order-by

I have two tables, `movies` and `categories`, and I want to get an ordered list by **categoryID** first and then by **Name**.

The movie table has three columns **ID, Name and CategoryID**.
The category table has two columns **ID and Name**.

I tried something like the following, but it didn't work.

```
var movies = _db.Movies.OrderBy( m => { m.CategoryID, m.Name })
```

Comment: Here is why this can't work: The lambda expression in the parentheses is supposed to return a value which can be used to order the items: m.CategoryID is a number which can be used to order the items. But "m.CategoryID, m.Name" doesn't make sense in this context.

Comment: .ThenBy is what you're searching?

Comment: If by any chance you want to sort them in descending order there [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1635506/465053) is the way to go.

Answer (score 3201, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
var movies = _db.Movies.OrderBy(c => c.Category).ThenBy(n => n.Name)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer of course... 
But instead of 
`Var movies = _db.Movies.Orderby(c => c.Category).ThenBy(n => n.Name)` 

if I use
`Var movies = _db.Movies.Orderby(c => c.Category).OrderBy(n => n.Name)` 
2 times "orderBy" why is the result different?

Comment: @devendra, result is different because second "OrderBy" works over the collection which is result of first "OrderBy" and reorder its items

Comment: ThenBy operates on IOrderedEnumerable (which is returned by OrderBy)

Comment: Please note: `.ThenBy()` = Ascending, and `.ThenByDescending()` = Descending!! (sounds logical, huh?)

Comment: IQueryable<class> does not contain a definition for ThenBy

Comment: If you want your data to be in descending order, you can use as below:  
`Var movies = _db.Movies.OrderByDescending(c => c.Category).ThenByDescending(n => n.Name)`

Comment: OrderBy should be implemented like SmartOrderBy. Thanks to this so many people wouldn't fall into this trap. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44438959/669692

Comment: Very strange. Normally when you sort, you sort by the most important attribute last, not first. Also (in a logical language) you'd think a sort would not produce random results when the attributes have the same values, you'd expect nothing to happen. Yet in dot net, you have to be careful and use a special call "ThenBy". Uh. Looking at the documentation, it is not be made clear ThenBy will preserve the order of the previous sort.

Answer (score 633):

Using non-lambda, query-syntax LINQ, you can do this:

```
var movies = from row in _db.Movies 
             orderby row.Category, row.Name
             select row;
```

[EDIT to address comment] To control the sort order, use the keywords `ascending` (which is the default and therefore not particularly useful) or `descending`, like so:

```
var movies = from row in _db.Movies 
             orderby row.Category descending, row.Name
             select row;
```

Comment: There's not a way to flip back and forth between descending and non in this syntax is there?

Comment: Actually, your answer is the equivalent to `_db.Movies.Orderby(c => c.Category).OrderBy(n => n.Name)`. More correct is `from row in _db.Movies orderby row.Category descending orderby row.Name select row`

Comment: @Lodewijk: I believe you have that exactly backwards.  Your example will end up having row.Name being the primary column and row.Category secondary, which is the equivalent of `_db.Movies.Orderby(c => c.Category).OrderBy(n => n.Name)`.  The two snippets you provide are equivalent to each other, not to the OP's.

Comment: The only downside to using the SQL syntax for Linq is that not all of the functions are supported, most but not all

Answer (score 83):

Add "new":

```
var movies = _db.Movies.OrderBy( m => new { m.CategoryID, m.Name })
```

That works on my box. It does return something that can be used to sort. It returns an object with two values.

Similar, but different to sorting by a combined column, as follows.

```
var movies = _db.Movies.OrderBy( m => (m.CategoryID.ToString() + m.Name))
```

Comment: Be careful when using that for numbers.

Comment: Your answer is great, because it works in JSLINQ (where I dont have "ThenBy()"), but I have one more problem. How to use this when I want to have CategoryID descending and Name ascending?

Comment: You can use OrderByDescending and ThenBy, or OrderBy and ThenByDescending, depending upon your need.

Comment: @Arvangen, a twisted way to do this would be to go with something like "OrderBy(m => new { - m.CategoryID, m.Name })". I haven't tested it out, but it should do what you want

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `.OrderBy( m => new { m.CategoryID, m.Name })` and `.OrderBy( m => new { m.Name, m.CategoryID })` will produce the same results rather than respecting the intended priority.  It will sometimes appear to give you the ordering you want purely by coincidence.  Additionally `m.CategoryID.ToString() + m.Name` will produce incorrect orderings if CategoryID is an `int`.  For example, something with id=123, name=5times will appear after id=1234, name=something instead of before.  It's also not inefficient to do string comparisons where int comparisons could occur.

Comment: When I try to order by on an anonymous type, I get an ArgumentException with the message "At least one object must implement IComparable.".  I see others having to declare a comparer when doing this.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10356864/linq-orderby-anonymous-object-with-projection-comparer .

Comment: My bad, this works with string properties; I was testing with int properties.

Comment: `OrderBy( m => new { m.CategoryID, m.Name })` doesn't work, it throws exception  "At least one object must implement IComparable".

Comment: This is absolutely wrong.  Ordering by a new anonymous type that has no ICompariable implementation cannot work, because there is not order to the properties of an anonymous type.  It wouldn't know whether to sort on CategoryID first or Name first, let alone if they were to be sorted in opposite orders.

Comment: I just mentioned the anonymous type does work if you can't use ThenBy.

Comment: The technique with the anonymous type, `m => new { m.CategoryID, m.Name }`, __will not work with Linq-to-Objects__ because as others already said in comments above, an anonymous type is neither `IComparable` nor `IComparable<>`. It may and may not work with other LINQ providers (Linq-to-Sql?) depending on whether the "engine" in question has a way of translating the expression tree containing the anonymous type into something meaningful (like a valid SQL query).

Answer (score 46):

Use the following line on your `DataContext` to log the SQL activity on the `DataContext` to the console - then you can see exactly what your LINQ statements are requesting from the database:

```
_db.Log = Console.Out
```

The following LINQ statements:

```
var movies = from row in _db.Movies 
             orderby row.CategoryID, row.Name
             select row;
```

AND

```
var movies = _db.Movies.OrderBy(m => m.CategoryID).ThenBy(m => m.Name);
```

produce the following SQL:

```sql
SELECT [t0].ID, [t0].[Name], [t0].CategoryID
FROM [dbo].[Movies] as [t0]
ORDER BY [t0].CategoryID, [t0].[Name]
```

Whereas, repeating an `OrderBy` in LINQ, appears to reverse the resulting SQL output:

```
var movies = from row in _db.Movies 
             orderby row.CategoryID
             orderby row.Name
             select row;
```

AND

```
var movies = _db.Movies.OrderBy(m => m.CategoryID).OrderBy(m => m.Name);
```

produce the following SQL (Name and CategoryId are switched):

```sql
SELECT [t0].ID, [t0].[Name], [t0].CategoryID
FROM [dbo].[Movies] as [t0]
ORDER BY [t0].[Name], [t0].CategoryID
```

Answer (score 37):

I have created some extension methods (below) so you don't have to worry if an IQueryable is already ordered or not. If you want to order by multiple properties just do it as follows:

```
// We do not have to care if the queryable is already sorted or not. 
// The order of the Smart* calls defines the order priority
queryable.SmartOrderBy(i => i.Property1).SmartOrderByDescending(i => i.Property2);
```

**This is especially helpful if you create the ordering dynamically, f.e. from a list of properties to sort.**

```
public static class IQueryableExtension
{
    public static bool IsOrdered<T>(this IQueryable<T> queryable) {
        if(queryable == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("queryable");
        }

        return queryable.Expression.Type == typeof(IOrderedQueryable<T>);
    }

    public static IQueryable<T> SmartOrderBy<T, TKey>(this IQueryable<T> queryable, Expression<Func<T, TKey>> keySelector) {
        if(queryable.IsOrdered()) {
            var orderedQuery = queryable as IOrderedQueryable<T>;
            return orderedQuery.ThenBy(keySelector);
        } else {
            return queryable.OrderBy(keySelector);
        }
    }

    public static IQueryable<T> SmartOrderByDescending<T, TKey>(this IQueryable<T> queryable, Expression<Func<T, TKey>> keySelector) {
        if(queryable.IsOrdered()) {
            var orderedQuery = queryable as IOrderedQueryable<T>;
            return orderedQuery.ThenByDescending(keySelector);
        } else {
            return queryable.OrderByDescending(keySelector);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is gold! I'll combine the check for queryable.IsOrdered() with the answer from this post, to have a single method that takes a sort direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388708/

Comment: This way Linq implementation should go in the first place! OrderBy is badly designed...

Comment: You can easily extend this extension in order to consider nullable values. Refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36507021

Answer (score 19):

There is at least one more way to do this using LINQ, although not the easiest.
You can do it by using the `OrberBy()` method that uses an `IComparer`. First you need to 
implement an `IComparer` for the `Movie` class like this:

```
public class MovieComparer : IComparer<Movie>
{
    public int Compare(Movie x, Movie y)
    {
        if (x.CategoryId == y.CategoryId)
        {
            return x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name);
        }
        else
        {
            return x.CategoryId.CompareTo(y.CategoryId);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can order the movies with the following syntax:

```
var movies = _db.Movies.OrderBy(item => item, new MovieComparer());
```

If you need to switch the ordering to descending for one of the items just switch the x and y inside the `Compare()` 
method of the `MovieComparer` accordingly.

Comment: I like this as being more general than thenby since you can do weird things with the compare including having different compare objects with different algorithms ready to go.  This is better than my preferred solution before learning about thenby which was to create a class that implements the IComparable interface.

Comment: Since 2012 (.NET version 4.5) you do not have to create a class `MovieComparer` yourself; instead you can do `_db.Movies.OrderBy(item => item, Comparer<Movie>.Create((x, y) => { if (x.CategoryId == y.CategoryId)
        {
            return x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name);
        }
        else
        {
            return x.CategoryId.CompareTo(y.CategoryId);
        } }));`. Of course, if you prefer to write the logic as one expression, instead of `if`...`else`, then the lamda `(x, y) => expr` can be simpler.

Answer (score 6):

If use generic repository

```
> lstModule = _ModuleRepository.GetAll().OrderBy(x => new { x.Level,
> x.Rank}).ToList();
```

else

```
> _db.Module.Where(x=> ......).OrderBy(x => new { x.Level, x.Rank}).ToList();
```

Comment: Anonymous expressions will be parsed locally by entity framework core. The LINQ expression could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.