# ascending/descending in LINQ - can one change the order via parameter?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a method which is given the parameter "bool sortAscending". Now I want to use LINQ to create sorted list depending on this parameter. I got then this:

```
var ascendingQuery = from data in dataList
                      orderby data.Property ascending
                      select data;

var descendingQuery = from data in dataList
                      orderby data.Property descending
                      select data;
```

As you can see, both queries differ only in "ascending" resp. "descending". I'd like to merge both queries, but I don't know how. Does anyone have the answer?

Comment: So you want to have one query that can do both ascending or descending depending on the bool sortAsvending value? Is that correct.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

You can easily create your own extension method on IEnumerable or IQueryable:

```
public static IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> OrderByWithDirection<TSource,TKey>
    (this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
     Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
     bool descending)
{
    return descending ? source.OrderByDescending(keySelector)
                      : source.OrderBy(keySelector);
}

public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> OrderByWithDirection<TSource,TKey>
    (this IQueryable<TSource> source,
     Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector,
     bool descending)
{
    return descending ? source.OrderByDescending(keySelector)
                      : source.OrderBy(keySelector);
}
```

Yes, you lose the ability to use a query expression here - but frankly I don't think you're actually benefiting from a query expression anyway in this case. Query expressions are great for complex things, but if you're only doing a single operation it's simpler to just put that one operation:

```
var query = dataList.OrderByWithDirection(x => x.Property, direction);
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting my stupidity Marc :) (That's the problem with posting just before going to lunch...)

Comment: This post was answered and edited by two celebrities of SO.com

Comment: shouldn't one of the OrderByWithDirections return ascending?

Comment: @KOL: I'm not sure what you mean. Both of them will return ascending if you pass in `false` for `descending`.

Comment: @JonSkeet, thanks for the solution, but I've posted a question regarding its usage.  see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18348767/orderbywithdirection-when-direction-depends-on-data

Answer (score 48):

In terms of how this is implemented, this changes the *method* - from OrderBy/ThenBy to OrderByDescending/ThenByDescending. However, you can apply the sort separately to the main query...

```
var qry = from .... // or just dataList.AsEnumerable()/AsQueryable()

if(sortAscending) {
    qry = qry.OrderBy(x=>x.Property);
} else {
    qry = qry.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Property);
}
```

Any use? You can create the entire "order" dynamically, but it is more involved...

Another trick (mainly appropriate to LINQ-to-Objects) is to use a multiplier, of -1/1. This is only really useful for numeric data, but is a cheeky way of achieving the same outcome.

Comment: I was just about to write this exact same thing then my VS froze :(

Comment: Using a multiplier also fails for a return value of int.MinValue.

Comment: why do you use the orderBy-method instead of using the orderby keyword in a linq-query?

Comment: @Joshit because I need to do different operations in the two cases, and there's no benefit in using LINQ query syntax here over just using the extension method. If you prefer the query syntax: go do that, it'll be fine.

Comment: @MarcGravell thank you very much for your quick response!! I thought, if two luminaries of performance programming do it that way, its worth asking if there are any deeper reasons ;)

Comment: @Joshit contrast: `qry = from x in qry orderby x.Property descending select x;` vs `qry = qry.OrderByDescending(x => x.Property);` - I just find the latter cleaner; it is clear that I'm only trying to do one thing - the `OrderBy`. They work the same, though.

Comment: @MarcGravell thank you again!! I always try to do the things I do for a good reason. Readability is one, and if it´s not beaten by performance it´s a good one ;)  I´d do it the same now...

Answer (score 8):

What about ordering desc by the desired property,

```
   blah = blah.OrderByDescending(x => x.Property);
```

And then doing something like

```
  if (!descending)
  {
       blah = blah.Reverse()
  }
  else
  {
      // Already sorted desc ;)
  }
```

Is it Reverse() too slow?

Comment: Probably not the most optimized, but surely a very clever approach

Comment: @DiegoPenha humm but in case it were linq to entities before materializing data should be the same, isn't? I mean will produce an sql query accordingly. You agree?

Comment: @DiegoPenha forget it, linq to entities doesn't support .Reverse() function 

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the beautiful solution given by @Jon Skeet, I also needed ThenBy and ThenByDescending, so I am adding it based on his solution:

```
    public static IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> ThenByWithDirection<TSource, TKey>(
         this IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> source, 
         Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,  
         bool descending)
    {
        return descending ? 
               source.ThenByDescending(keySelector) :
               source.ThenBy(keySelector);
    }
```