# Get HeaderClick event of a WPF listview

Tags: wpf, events, listview, wpf-controls

How can I get the headerclick event of a WPF Listview?

Comment: Seriously! Why couldn't you Google or look at MSDN for this information?!

Comment: Yeah hard to disagree, Dennis. I guess because it's "GridViewColumnHeader" it might be a bit hard to search for, but it probably would've been easier than typing in the question and waiting for an answer.

Comment: If you're pretty new to WPF, it isn't that obvious that the event exists. It's neither in the Properties pane nor in IntelliSense in Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the GridViewColumnHeader.Click attached event. As an example, see the MSDN page on [sorting a GridView when the header is clicked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745786.aspx).

```
<ListView x:Name='lv' 
          Height="150" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
          VerticalAlignment="Center" 
          GridViewColumnHeader.Click="GridViewColumnHeaderClickedHandler">
```

Comment: Events that apply to children like that won't show up in Intellisense - the editor can't know which ones you might want to use!

Comment: worked perfectly and this is how i got the bound column, 
                \string columnProperty = ((Binding)columnHeader.Column.DisplayMemberBinding).Path.Path;

Comment: Link is broken. Try this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745786(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

just to expand on the previous answer, how to know which header was clicked on:

XAML:

```
<ListView GridViewColumnHeader.Click="GridViewColumnHeaderClickedHandler">
```

CS:

```
private void SortHeaderClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(((GridViewColumnHeader)e.OriginalSource).Column.Header.ToString());
}
```

Comment: If somebody is searching for the possibility to sort ListView items by ordered LINQ query after acquaring the WPF ListView EventHandler, then there is a compact solution:  var query = dataList.OrderByWithDirection(x => x.Property, direction); <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388708/ascending-descending-in-linq-can-one-change-the-order-via-parameter>