# Ordering and subordering a list using a lambda

Tags: c#, lambda

I need to order a list by status == "Rejected" and date ascending and then by status == "Accepted" and date descending.

I am trying the following but I'm not sure how to go about this:

```
items
   .OrderBy(x => x.status == "Rejected") 
   .ThenBy(x => x.DateSubmitted)
   .ThenBy(x => x.status == "Accepted") 
   .ThenByDescending(x => x.DateSubmitted)
```

Comment: that's a lot of orderning!  is this data coming from a Database?  If so, it probably would be best to order there.

Comment: Are there any other status options?

Comment: Yes there are others. The other ones need to be ordered by date

Comment: [Custom OrderByWithDirection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388708/ascending-descending-in-linq-can-one-change-the-order-via-parameter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're describing the task a bit awkward, which (I think) leads you to a slightly wrong implementation.

I say:

```
items
   .Where(x => x.status == "Rejected") 
   .OrderBy(x => x.DateSubmitted)
   .Concat(items.
       .Where(x => x.status == "Accepted") 
       .OrderByDescending(x => x.DateSubmitted));
```

The main difference is that now, status other than "Rejected" or "Accepted" are not shown.
However, I think it is what you intended. If you want the full set, consider using

```
items
   .Where(x => x.status == "Rejected") 
   .OrderBy(x => x.DateSubmitted)
   .Concat(items.
       .Where(x => x.status != "Rejected") 
       .OrderByDescending(x => x.DateSubmitted));
```

PS. This is also assuming Linq-To-Objects. I'm not very well-versed with Linq-to-EF or Linq-to-SQL