# Custom OrderBy extension method fails while projecting anonymous type

Tags: c#, linq, linqpad

In reference to [the answer proposed in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388708/ascending-descending-in-linq-can-one-change-the-order-via-parameter/17773710?noredirect=1#comment25923118_17773710), can anyone explain why LINQPad won't generate any SQL for this?

```
var query = Products.Select(p => new 
{ 
    Orders = p.Orders.OrderByWithDirection(x => x.PurchaseDate, true) 
});
```

The exception is as follows:

> NotSupportedException: Method 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable`1[LINQPad.User.Order] OrderByWithDirection[Phase,String](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[LINQ‌​Pad.User.Order], System.Func`2[LINQPad.User.Order,System.String], Boolean)' has no supported translation to SQL.

Comment: Well what's the error? We can't really help if we don't know what's happening.

Comment: Maybe it's due to deferred execution? Does any SQL get generated if you issue `var results = query.ToList()`?

Comment: @JonSkeet: The exception is as follows:
 NotSupportedException: Method 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable`1[LINQPad.User.Order] OrderByWithDirection[Phase,String](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[LINQPad.User.Order], System.Func`2[LINQPad.User.Order,System.String], Boolean)' has no supported translation to SQL.

Comment: @Douglas: No SQL will be generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not that it's part of an anonymous type - the problem is that you don't actually call `OrderByWithDirection` directly... instead, you build up an expression tree *within the projection* and that expression tree contains a reference to `OrderByWithDirection`, which LINQ to SQL (or EF, or whatever) doesn't know about.

I can't think of any nice fix for this other than an expression tree visitor which goes through the expression tree and replaces the call with either `OrderBy` or `OrderByDescending` based on the second argument - which would have to be a constant, of course. Even that's going to be far from trivial.

To be honest, I would probably take a low-tech approach - keep as much of the query the same as you can, and then conditionally call `OrderBy` or `OrderByDescending` at the end:

```
var mainQuery = ...; // Stuff which is in common

var query = direction
    ? mainQuery.Select(p => new { Orders = p.Orders.OrderBy(x => x.PurchaseDate) })
    : mainQuery.Select(p => new { Orders = p.Orders.OrderByDescending(x => x.PurchaseDate) });
```

As an aside, I assume your real query has more properties in the anonymous type? There's rarely any good reason to create an anonymous type with a single property.

Comment: Thank you. It would have been great if there is an easier fix than rebuilding the expression tree...

Comment: I am already using the low-tech approach you proposed, but the code is getting scary because the queries are huge.