# OrderByWithDirection when direction depends on data

Tags: c#, linq

In this SO article: [ascending/descending in LINQ - can one change the order via parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388708/ascending-descending-in-linq-can-one-change-the-order-via-parameter) a solution was presented for how to conditionally order in ascending or descending order.

what the article doesn't cover is, what if I want to make the decision based on the data in the query (which is, actually, what is most likely)?

I cannot seem to do:

```
source.OrderByWithDirection(o => o.MyColumnToOrderBy, o => o.SortingDirection)
```

would I then need to rewrite the methods? how?

**- update -**

by way of rationale, here is what I'm looking to accomplish:

```
Strike  Type Price
98      Ask  101
98      Ask  100
98      Ask  99
98      Bid  95
98      Bid  96
98      Bid  97
```

as you can see, asks are sorted down but bids are sorted up such that the rows with the greatest difference are next to each other.  so what I'd like to say is something like:

```
source.OrderBy(o => new { o.Strike, o.Type })
  .ThenByWithDirection(o => o.Price, o => o.Type == "Ask" ? __down__ : __up__)
```

**- update II -**

a clumsy way to do this would be to issue two separate queries like this:

```
source
  .Where(o => o.Type == "Ask")
  .OrderBy(o => new { o.Strike, o.Type })
  .ThenBy(o => o.Price)

source
  .Where(o => o.Type == "Bid")
  .OrderBy(o => new { o.Strike, o.Type })
  .ThenByDescending(o => o.Price)
```

and concatenate them

Comment: `o` is an member of the IEnumerable?  What if different elements had different values for SortingDirection?  Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @bmm6o, `o` represent a record within the query.  different records will have different values for `o.SortingDirection`, which is the point of my question

Comment: For what it's worth, while it may be "most likely" to you, it's not something I've ever heard requested before - whereas the ability to simply have a programmatic ascending/descending, usually based on user input to the query (rather than the data within the question) is a fairly common request.

Comment: It's also not clear what your query would even mean - what if each row had a different sorting direction, or a different column to sort by? How can you sort all of the results in that case? You need *one* set of ordering criteria (including direction) for the whole query, surely. More details on your use case - including sample data and expected output - would be helpful.

Comment: You will have to show us some sample data and the output you expect, because what you are asking for doesn't make any sense right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have your entities/objects, but can you not just do something like:

```
var items = from t in source
    select new { a = t, b = t.Type == "Ask" ? -t.Price : t.Price };
var sorted = from x in items
     orderby x.a.Type, x.b
     select x.a;
```

That is, create a new object that contains a single property by which you *can* perform a sort, and then use that in your ordering operations?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a generic extension Method for that:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> OrderByString<T>(this IEnumerable<T> entities, string sortExpression)
        {

            bool descending = sortExpression.ToLowerInvariant().Trim().EndsWith("desc");

            PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos = typeof(T).GetProperties();
            // sort properties by name
            foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in propertyInfos)
            {
                if (sortExpression.Split(' ')[0] == propertyInfo.Name)
                {
                    PropertyInfo info = propertyInfo;
                    if (descending)
                        return entities.OrderByDescending(c => info.GetValue(c, null));
                    else
                        return entities.OrderBy(c => info.GetValue(c, null));
                }
            }
            return entities;
        }
```

Usage:

```
IEnumerable x = cars.OrderByString("color desc");
```

Hope it helps.

Daniel

Comment: thanks @Daniel but your answer is also missing the mark, like those of the other 2 posters

Answer (score 1):

One way is to extract the information into a more meaningful structure for sorting:

```
source
    .Select(o => new {
        o.Strike,
        o.Type,
        o.Price,
        o.AskPrice = o.Type == "Ask" ? o.Price : (int)null,
        o.BidPrice = o.Type == "Bid" ? o.Price : (int)null
    })
    .OrderBy(o => o.Strike)
    .ThenBy(o => o.Type)
    .ThenByDescending(o => o.AskPrice)
    .ThenBy(o => o.BidPrice)
```

This assumes you know that these are the two things you want to sort by.

Another option would be to invert one of your values (e.g. for sorting purposes use 1000000 - AskPrice, then it could be sorted ascending).

Comment: this is very similar to what Damien posted, but in a way I prefer it because the logic is very clear.  thank you, that will solve my problem (I will leave Damien's as the answer just because he got there first but you got a point for this).  thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The answer with the IComparer is close, but needs to be like this:

```
public class BidComparer : IComparer<BidDatum> {
    public int Compare(BidDatum x, BidDatum y) {
        return (x.Type != y.Type) ? (x.Type.CompareTo(y.Type)) : ((x.Type == "Ask") ? y.Price.CompareTo(x.Price) : x.Price.CompareTo(y.Price));
    }
}
```

Now your Linq can look like this:

```
var ans = srcData.OrderBy(d => d.Strike).ThenBy(d => d, new BidComparer());
```

I skipped a `.ThenBy(d => d.Type)` since the custom IComparer also sorts Ask before Bid.

Answer (score 0):

You can try custom `IComparer`:

```
public class MyComparer<T> : IComparer<T> {
   public MyComparer(bool ascending){
      Descending = !ascending;
   }
   public bool Descending {get;set;}
   public int Compare(T x, T y){
      //your normal logic
      int result = ....;
      return Descending ? -result : result;
   }
}
```

Then use it in your `OrderBy` query:

```
source.OrderBy(o=>o.MyColumnToOrderBy, new MyComparer(true));//true for ascending and false for descending
```

### UPDATE

You can use some `enum` instead of `bool` to indicate the sorting direction:

```
public class MyComparer<T> : IComparer<T> {
   public MyComparer(SortingDirection sortDir){
      Direction = sortDir;
   }
   public SortingDirection Direction {get;set;}
   public int Compare(T x, T y){
      //your normal logic
      int result = ....;
      return Direction == SortingDirection.Descending ? -result : result;
   }
   public enum SortingDirection {
     Ascending,
     Descending
   }
}
//o.SortingDirection should be type of enum SortingDirection
source.OrderBy(o=>o.MyColumnToOrderBy, new MyComparer(o.SortingDirection));
```

**Another work-around**

I think you can use a little trick with `GroupBy` to order by `o.SortingDirection`, like this:

```
source.GroupBy(x=>x.MyColumnToOrderBy)
      .SelectMany(g=> o.SortingDirection == SortingDirection.Ascending ? 
                                            g.OrderBy(a=>a.Key) :
                                            g.OrderByDescending(a=>a.Key));
```

Comment: oh... I hadn't realised you could pass a comparer, however, I still have the same problem.  in your example you pass the literal `true` but in my case I need that decision to be made on the basis of the data in the query... could I then do: `o => new MyComparer(o.SortingDirection)`?

Comment: @ekkis of course, we have only 2 kinds of `SortingDirection`, I used a `bool` but you can define some `enum` like `SortingDirection` which has `SortingDirection.Ascending` and `SortingDirection.Descending`.

Comment: no, my issue is not that there is more than one sorting direction.  it is that the decision is not made statically, like when you pass `true`.  it is dynamic and depends on values within the query, but I see you addressed that.  I'm looking into it...

Comment: @ekkis could you name any other direction except `Ascending` and `Descending`? You have to convert all other values to one of those directions.

Comment: but in any case, the code as you posted in the update does not compile.  I tried it the way you stated (except it needs a type so I did `new MyComparer<decimal>(...)`) as well as `source.OrderBy(o => o.MyColumnToOrderBy, x => new MyComparer<decimal>(x.SortingDirection)` and `source.OrderBy(o => o.MyColumntoOrderBy, new MyComparer<decimal>(x => x.SortingDirection)` but no dice

Comment: @ekkis there are 2 solutions in my update, what about the second? Could you post the exception/error saying why it didn't compile? If the code before update compiles OK, the code in the update should also compile OK.

Comment: I think this is close, but the comparer doesn't use the right criteria. I added an answer based on this.

Comment: @NetMage my solution is just a general solution, not very specific. You can see the line `var result = ...` that's what the OP should fill to calculate the normal comparison (for the ascending order). Then we can just return the  inverse value to have it in descending order..

Answer (score 0):

I think in general you would have a hard time implementing your proposed `OrderByWithDirection`.  What would the result be for e.g. the data set `{1, true}, {2, false}, {3, true}, {4, false}`?  The only reason it works in your case is that your second sort has a high correlation with your first one, i.e. the second sort never needs to compare a "bid" and an "ask".

The best way to approach this is with a custom IComparator that implements the whole sort.  Something like:

```
int Compare(Entry a, Entry b)
{
    if (a.Type == b.Type)
    {
        // same type, look at the price difference and reverse if they are both Bids
        return a.Price.CompareTo(b.Price) * (a.Type == "Bid" ? -1 : 1);
    }
    else
    {
        // different types, Ask comes first
        return (a.Type == "Ask") ? -1 : 1;
    }
}
```