# Orderby ASC/DESC when certain state

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to filter on certain elements in my table, but when there is a certain state in the table I want to filte the same in decending.

*Example*:

> When the state is "Open" I want to filter on "tijdSluit" ascending. When te state is "Gesloten" I want to filter on "tijdSluit" descending.

*The code I use now*:

```
return View(db.GetAllRequests().OrderBy(Request => Request.request.Status).ThenBy(Request => Request.request.tijdSluit));
```

The problem is that you can't filter on ascending and descending in the same table. How can I fix this?

*I tried this*:

```
return View(db.GetAllRequests().Where(Request => Request.request.Status == 1).OrderBy(Request => Request.request.Status).Where(Request => Request.request.Status != 1).OrderByDescending(Request => Request.request.tijdSluit));
```

But when I run that code I get a empty table.

How can I do this correct?

Comment: If the data returned is empty, then check why it is empty, ordering will not affect the no. of results you will get

Comment: @BonMacalindong It is because there is a `Where`.

Comment: You can't order your data in 2 ways. It's either in descending or in ascending. What you want to do is write an if on your 'state' and do the sorting depending on that.

Comment: @Thomas I know it is not possible, that is why i am asking. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ascending/descending in LINQ - can one change the order via parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388708/ascending-descending-in-linq-can-one-change-the-order-via-parameter)

Comment: @MaxA yes but you said "But when I run that code I get a empty table." which make the question irrelevant to orderby TBH

Comment: @BonMacalindong the empty table is not the problem, it is only why that way didn't work.

Comment: @MaxA yes i know your problem, im just pointing out your last statement is kinda confusing. Anyways, its either you do an if statement or an extension method which will encapsulate your state checking with ordering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ofcourse, it isn't possible to order you table asc and desc at the same time. Maybe in your case you need two ordered sequences? Somwthing like this?

```
var allRequests = db.GetAllRequests();
var openRequests = allRequests.Where(Request => Request.request.Status == 1).OrderBy(Request => Request.request.Status).ToList();
var otherRequests = allRequests.Where(Request => Request.request.Status != 1).OrderByDescending(Request => Request.request.tijdSluit)).ToList();
openRequests.AddRange(otherRequests);
return View(openRequests);
```

Comment: Error: "Cannot convert from 'void' to 'object'."