# How can i make "s.Id" and "ascending" in the Linq statement dynamic?

Tags: c#, linq

How can i make "s.Id" and "ascending" in the Linq statement dynamic?

`var orderedList = from s in this.myList orderby s.Id ascending select s;`

thanks

Comment: How dynamic does it have to be? How will you get the field to be used for ordering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var param = "Id";
var direction = "asc";

var propertyInfo = myList[0].GetType().GetProperty(param);
var orderById = myList.Select(x => new { item = x, sort = propertyInfo.GetValue(x) })
        .OrderBy(x => direction == "asc" ? x.sort : 0)
        .OrderByDescending(x => direction == "desc" ? x.sort : 0)
        .Select(x => x.item)
        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
var param = "Id";    
var propertyInfo = typeof(yourObject).GetProperty(param);    
var orderById = this.myList.OrderBy(x => propertyInfo.GetValue(x, null));
```

Comment: Why all that reflection thing?

Comment: you can pass dynamic order by variable

Comment: Oh, I see. The ascending/descending thing is still not dynamic though.

Comment: what do you mean by ascending ? its orderBy is by default asc

Comment: He said he wants both the field and the "ascending/descending" order dynamic. With your code only the field is dynamic.

Comment: probably this should help him https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388708/ascending-descending-in-linq-can-one-change-the-order-via-parameter