# OrderBy selected DateTime column(Column name string) from datatable C#

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, datatable, sql-order-by

I filled a datatable from excel as dt3. Now I am trying to use linq to select a DateTime column from the datatable as a list and I want it in ascending order. I have using System.Linq.Dynamic; as reference however I am not sure I am using it right.

```
public List<DateTime?> GetDocAvailDates(System.Data.DataTable dt3)

{

List<DateTime?> DateList = dt3.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<DateTime?>("Doc Available")).Distinct().ToList();

          return DateList;
}
```

I have tried

```
    public List<DateTime?> GetDocAvailDates(System.Data.DataTable dt3)
            {
                List<DateTime?> DateList = dt3.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<DateTime?>("Doc Available")).

OrderBy("Doc Available")
OrderBy(r => r.Field<DateTime?>("Doc Available"))
OrderBy(orderby) with a string orderby = "Doc Available"; 


.Distinct().ToList();

              return DateList;

            }
```

None have worked. Please advise. Thanks

Comment: You can refer to here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388708/ascending-descending-in-linq-can-one-change-the-order-via-parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
List<DateTime?> DateList = dt3.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<DateTime?>("Doc Available")).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
```

After the `Disctinct()`, actually already after the `Select()`, you already have an enumeration of `DateTime?`. So, you order by the value itself.

```
OrderBy(x => x) // x can be any name that is not used in the same scope.
```

Note, that you have to use `OrderBy()` after `Distinct()`, because `Distinct()` can change the order of the elements again.