# OrderBy descending in Lambda expression?

Tags: linq, lambda

I know in normal Linq grammar, `orderby xxx descending` is very easy, but how do I do this in Lambda expression?

Answer (score 446, accepted):

As Brannon says, it's [`OrderByDescending`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending.aspx) and [`ThenByDescending`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.thenbydescending.aspx):

```
var query = from person in people
            orderby person.Name descending, person.Age descending
            select person.Name;
```

is equivalent to:

```
var query = people.OrderByDescending(person => person.Name)
                  .ThenByDescending(person => person.Age)
                  .Select(person => person.Name);
```

Comment: "order by person.Name descending" should be "*orderby* person.Name descending"

Answer (score 64):

Use `System.Linq.Enumerable.OrderByDescending()`?

For example:

```
var items = someEnumerable.OrderByDescending();
```

Answer (score 22):

Try this:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
list.Add(1);
list.Add(5);
list.Add(4);
list.Add(3);
list.Add(2);

foreach (var item in list.OrderByDescending(x => x))
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);                
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Try this another way:

```
var qry = Employees
          .OrderByDescending (s => s.EmpFName)
          .ThenBy (s => s.Address)
          .Select (s => s.EmpCode);
```

[Queryable.ThenBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535112.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

This only works in situations where you have a numeric field, but you can put a minus sign in front of the field name like so:

```
reportingNameGroups = reportingNameGroups.OrderBy(x=> - x.GroupNodeId);
```

However this works a little bit different than `OrderByDescending` when you have are running it on an `int?` or `double?` or `decimal?` fields.

What will happen is on `OrderByDescending` the nulls will be at the end, vs with this method the nulls will be at the beginning. Which is useful if you want to shuffle nulls around without splitting data into pieces and splicing it later.

Answer (score 1):

`LastOrDefault()` is usually not working but with the `Tolist()` it will work. There is no need to use `OrderByDescending` use `Tolist()` like this.

```
GroupBy(p => p.Nws_ID).ToList().LastOrDefault();
```