# Order by a field descendingly

Tags: c#

I achieve this in this way

```
UnUsedServices = UnUsedServices.OrderBy(si => si.utility).ToList(); //order it ascendingly
UnUsedServices.Reverse();//reverse it
```

I just wonder is there a way to reverse it directly in **descending** order instead of splitting into two phases (sort ascending and reverse)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635497/orderby-descending-in-lambda-expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [OrderByDescending](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending.aspx)

```
UnUsedServices = UnUsedServices.OrderByDescending(si => si.utility).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try not to kick yourself: [OrderByDescending](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534855.aspx) :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in one shot if you want it in descending order by using OrderByDescending

```
UnUsedServices.OrderByDescending(si => si.utility).ToList();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending.aspx