# Order dates from closest to farthest from now

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of dates as strings in the format 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt' I'm trying to order them by closest to farthest like so:

```
09/12/2018 12:00:00 PM
10/12/2018 12:00:00 PM
11/12/2018 12:00:00 PM
```

My code seems to be ordering them from the 11th to the 09th which I don't want but can't seem to get right.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
var ordered = herds.HerdList.OrderBy(n => (now - DateTime.Parse(n.Date_Visit)).Duration());
```

The above code gives me:

```
11/12/2018 12:00:00 PM
10/12/2018 12:00:00 PM
09/12/2018 12:00:00 PM
```

How can I order it the other way around?

Thanks

Comment: _I have a list of dates as strings"_ Why the `Date_Visit`-dates are strings at all?

Comment: Just coming from the Web Service and sending to the Web Service. I parse it to a Date to work with in Time.

Comment: So basically get the date and time of when the object was created, turn to string and send to web service to be saved in the cloud.

Comment: Order by descending?

Comment: Omg, I'm this stupid ><. No coffee this morning I'll give that a shot there.

Comment: First step: Make your property `Date_Visit` of type `DateTime` and convert the incoming data accordingly. If this works as expected and you still have issues in ordering come back.

Comment: Order by descending worked...can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks, @KevinAvignon. Thanks for your input Oliver

Comment: This would make a great of any "Order by descending" from the linQ tag. As  "order it the other way around" is quite a uncommon way to call it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OrderBy descending in Lambda expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635497/orderby-descending-in-lambda-expression)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I order it the other way around?

Use `OrderByDescending` instead of `OrderBy`

Comment: You were first and saw you deleted the answer. Will mark this. Sorry for wasting your time, won't ask questions without coffee next time xD

Answer (score 1):

You can flip the order of any `Orderby(x => whatever)` by simply using `OrderByDescending(x => whatever)`.

Answer (score 1):

`var ordered = herds.HerdList.OrderBy(n => DateTime.Parse(n.Date_Visit));`