# LINQ Ordery by two fields

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I need to order a query result by two fields using LINQ.

How do I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [linq: multiple order by](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298725/linq-multiple-order-by)

Comment: It could be a duplicate but not for the keywords "LINQ Order by two fields". The subject is the same but I searched I simple could not find the question. Duplicate syndrome is pretty much the only problem with this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.OrderBy(x => x..)
.ThenBy(x => ..)
```