# C# Group by or something else?

Tags: c#, list

I have a List of type RGBComparison which I created. It has euclidean distance, id, local id, etc as variables. 
After I sort the List by distances I have an output like this;

```
1.35363 id=3 
1.43554 id=2 
1.4556  id=3
1.5  id = 35
1.6 id = 2
```

======================================

etc. They are sub images' euclidean distances(variable name distance) from the input subimage. I want to group them by keeping the original order. Consider there are 8 distances from image id 1 (and image id 1 is the closest one, 1st one in the list). I want an output like

```
    1.35363 id=3
    1.4556  id=3
    1.43554 id=2
    1.6 id=2
    1.5 id = 35

....
```

Is there a way to do this? Also I will only take max 5 distances from an input. For example, if id 1 has 8 submage distances in the List, then I will only take the first 5. Later I will show these subimages on the original image.

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298725/linq-multiple-order-by  I'd say duplicate but the only taking 5 from a group makes this interesting

Comment: thank you for the link. would that solution keep the original order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your have your data in a list `distances` you can use a combination of `OrderBy`/`GroupBy`, `Take` and finally `SelectMany` to flatten the result list:

```
var results = distances.OrderBy( x=> x.Id)
                       .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
                       .Select(g => g.OrderBy(x => x.Distance).Take(5))
                       .SelectMany(x => x)
                       .ToList() ;
```

To limit the number of distances to 5 max for each Id you do need the grouping, also use of an `OrderBy` before the grouping to induce the correct order of Ids which is preserved by the grouping.

**Edit in response to comment and clarification:**

```
   var results = distances.GroupBy(x => x.Id)
                          .Select(g => g.OrderBy(x => x.Distance).Take(5))
                          .SelectMany(x => x)
                          .OrderBy( x=> x.Distance)
                          .ToList();
```

This should give you a list sorted by distance, with at most 5 elements for any id.

Comment: I don't know how to use the output. I never used "var" before. How am I going to use the output results? I printed whats in it and it was consisted of mainscreen+ sth.

Comment: you can replace `var results` with `List<RGBComparison> results`, also its assumed distances is of type `List<RGBComparison>`

Comment: it doesnt keep the order. Gives very long distances on top of the list.

Comment: it sorts the id's, puts the smallest one on top but what I need is based on the distance, and then id's. Wish I knew anything about group by

Comment: perhaps I made a mistake by giving a biased example. 1.3434 id=35, 1.35656 id=1 is also an output.

Comment: I changed the example outputs in the question.

Comment: The output is grouped by id, for a given id the distances are sorted ascending, max 5 elements - if you wanted something else your example is confusing, since the output is clearly sorted by id first, then by distance. Please clarify.

Comment: I changed your code to accept
 

If your have your data in a list distances you can use a combination of OrderBy/GroupBy, Take and finally SelectMany to flatten the result list:

var results = distances.OrderBy( x=> x.distance)
                       .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
                       .Select(g => g.OrderBy(x => x.Distance).Take(5))
                       .SelectMany(x => x)
                       .ToList() ;
Now it works!

Comment: Thank you I hope my change in the code is true. I only did it by trying but according to the new examples, could the new code populate the right list?

Answer (score 0):

you can use LINQ to sort your list pretty easily

```
var myRGBComparisonList = new List<RGBComparison>();
//... populate list somewhere
var sortedSequence = from rgbComparison in myRGBComparisonList
                     orderby rgbComparison.ID ascending, rgbComparison.Distance ascending
                     select rgbComparison;
```

Comment: This doesn't restrict to max 5 elements per Id, for that you will need a grouping

Comment: yes and I don't have any idea about how to group them by 5 elements.

Comment: BrokenGlass's answer satisfies all the requirements