# LINQ Multiple Order By

Tags: c#, linq

I have 3 tables  Pamphlets, Categories and Program.  The Pamphlet table has a CategoryID and ProgramID column.  The following code works:

```
var pamphlets = db.Pamphlets.Include("Category").Include("Program").ToList();
```

What I need to do is sort by CategoryName (Category table) and then PamphletName (Pamphlet table).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple "order by" in LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298725/multiple-order-by-in-linq)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would simply chain a call to ThenBy():

```
var sortedPamphlets = db.Pamphlets.Include("Category").Include("Program")
                        .OrderBy(p => p.Category.CategoryName)
                        .ThenBy(p => p.PamphletName)
                        .ToList();
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to place `OrderBy` before `ToList` to give database a chance?

Comment: @Snowbear JIM-compiler - We had the same thought at the same time. Just made the change before I saw your comment.

Comment: Thanks!   I really appreciate that.  I knew it must be something simple.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
var pamphlets = (from p in db.Pamphlets.Include("Category").Include("Program")
                orderby p.Category.CategoryName, p.PamphletName
                select p).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var pamphlets = (from i in db.Pamphlets.Include("Category").Include("Program")
                 orderby i.Category.CategoryID, i.PamphletName
                 select i).ToList();
```