# Linq to Entities 4.1 - Group query forces ordering

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, group-by, ef-code-first

I'm developing an application using Entity Framework 4.1 Code First. The problem is when I try to group a query, it automatically adds an order by using the group key, overriding previous orderby statements. Here is the query:

```
using (var database = new Database())
{
    var query = from frame in database.Set<Frame>()
                orderby frame.DtStart, frame.DtStartMs
                group frame by frame.ReadoutID;
    Console.WriteLine(query.ToTraceString());
}
```

When I look at the generated sql (intercepting the dbquery's objectquery) I get the following:

```
SELECT
`Project2`.`devices_leituras_key`,
`Project2`.`C1`,
`Project2`.`devices_frames_key`,
`Project2`.`devices_key`,
`Project2`.`devices_leituras_key1`,
`Project2`.`devices_arquivos_key`,
`Project2`.`init_byte_arquivo`,
`Project2`.`dt_inicio`,
`Project2`.`dt_inicio_ms`,
`Project2`.`dt_fim`,
`Project2`.`dt_fim_ms`
FROM (SELECT
`Distinct1`.`devices_leituras_key`,
`Extent2`.`devices_frames_key`,
`Extent2`.`devices_key`,
`Extent2`.`devices_leituras_key` AS `devices_leituras_key1`,
`Extent2`.`devices_arquivos_key`,
`Extent2`.`init_byte_arquivo`,
`Extent2`.`dt_inicio`,
`Extent2`.`dt_inicio_ms`,
`Extent2`.`dt_fim`,
`Extent2`.`dt_fim_ms`,
CASE WHEN (`Extent2`.`devices_frames_key` IS  NULL) THEN (NULL)  ELSE (1) END AS `
C1`
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
`Extent1`.`devices_leituras_key`
FROM `devices_frames` AS `Extent1`) AS `Distinct1` LEFT OUTER JOIN `devices_frames`
AS `Extent2` ON `Distinct1`.`devices_leituras_key` = `Extent2`.`devices_leituras_key
`) AS `Project2`
 ORDER BY
`devices_leituras_key` ASC,
`C1` ASC
```

Note that there is some mapping between the Frame POCO e the table, for example the "ReadoutID" property to the "devices_leituras_key". However, the field C1 isnt present in the table.

Questions:
Why have the especified orderings gone missing (orderby frame.DtStart, frame.DtStartMs)?
Why did the ReadoutID e the other strange field ordering  ( ORDER BY `devices_leituras_key` ASC, `C1` ASC) appear?

When I remove the grouping, the original ordering aplies normally.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

LINQ-to-SQL and LINQ-to-Entities use remote model. Sequences in query implement the IQueryable and after the compilation resolve into query operators from the Queryable class, known as expression trees. Expression trees are **interpreted** by the runtime.

Change the order in your query and you shall be fine:

```
using (var database = new Database())
{
    var query = from frame in database.Set<Frame>()
    group frame by frame.ReadoutID;
    orderby frame.DtStart, frame.DtStartMs

    Console.WriteLine(query.ToTraceString());
}
```

Comment: After the groupby statement the 'frame' is no longer in scope; if I want to add a orderby after the group, I need to add an 'into' to continue modifying the query, and the target of the orderby will be now an IGroupable<int, Frame>, allowing me to order the generated groups, not the frames.

Comment: @Arthur yeah, you are right, my bet. Can you try multiple order by via `ThenBy`, like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298725/linq-multiple-order-by)

Comment: I tried making the query whitout using the query language sintax: 

`var query = database.Set<Frame>().OrderBy(f => f.DtStart).ThenBy(f => f.DtStartMs).GroupBy(f => f.ReadoutID);`

But i got the same result...