# How to order a linq query result by two different types fields

Tags: c#, winforms, linq-to-sql, sql-order-by, bindingsource

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple “order by” in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298725/multiple-order-by-in-linq)

I wonder how to order by two different types a query like the next:

```
            var qry = (from m in dc.Orders
                   select new { m.OrderDate, m.OrderID }).OrderBy(o=>o.OrderDate+o.OrderID).ToList();
        bindingSource1.DataSource = qry;
```

OrdrerDate is a date type and OrderID is an int type.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.thenby.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for `.ThenBy()`:

```
.OrderBy(o => o.OrderDate).ThenBy(o => o.OrderID).
```

Comment: Yes, that's it tank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would say:

```
 var qry = (from m in dc.Orders
                   select new { m.OrderDate, m.OrderID }).OrderBy(o=>o.OrderDate).ThenBy(o.OrderID).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var qry = (from m in dc.Orders 
               select new { m.OrderDate, m.OrderID }).OrderBy(o=>o.OrderDate).ThenBy(o.OrderID).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use ThenBy or you can write this Linq query :

```
var qry = (from m in dc.Orders
            orderby m.OrderDate, m.OrderID
    select new {m.OrderDate, m.OrderID}).ToList

        bindingSource1.DataSource = qry;
```