# Ordering within groups using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Given the following data:

```
List<Country> countries = new List<Country>();

countries.Add(new Country{ Name = "USA",     population=500000,  Year=2012 });
countries.Add(new Country{ Name = "USA",     population=300000,  Year=2002 });
countries.Add(new Country{ Name = "USA",     population=250000,  Year=1992 });
countries.Add(new Country{ Name = "USA",     population=20000,   Year=1982 });

countries.Add(new Country{ Name = "India",   population=1500000, Year=2012 });
countries.Add(new Country{ Name = "India",   population=1000000, Year=2002 });
countries.Add(new Country{ Name = "India",   population=50000,   Year=1982 });
countries.Add(new Country{ Name = "India",   population=80000,   Year=1992 });

countries.Add(new Country{ Name = "Germany", population=100000,  Year=2012 });
countries.Add(new Country{ Name = "Germany", population=400000,  Year=2002 });
countries.Add(new Country{ Name = "Germany", population=60000,   Year=1992 });
countries.Add(new Country{ Name = "Germany", population=4000,    Year=1982 });

countries.Add(new Country{ Name = "UK",      population=450000,  Year=2002 });
countries.Add(new Country{ Name = "UK",      population=50000,   Year=1992 });
countries.Add(new Country{ Name = "UK",      population=3000,    Year=1982 });
```

I want to order the countries by the largest population for a given year, but then display all the years for that country before moving on to the next country.

E.g.

1. 2012 - the population order would be India, USA, UK, Germany. So I would like the data to be ordered by all India data,  all USA data, all UK data and then Germany.
2. 2002 - the population order would be India, USA, Germany and then UK. UK is last because it has no 2002 data.

I want to achieve this using LINQ, although I've used LINQ in the past I'm struggling to get my head around this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You shoule add the result for detail what you expected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to group the data by country and then order by population for a particular year;

```
var year = 2002;    

var orderedCountries = countries
                        .GroupBy(c => c.Name)
                            .OrderByDescending(c => c.Where(y => y.Year == year).Select(p => p.population).FirstOrDefault())
                                .SelectMany(c=>c)  
                                .ToList();
```

The above code will work even if there is **no data for a given year**

That can be a bit much to read so you could separate out the logic in the orderby into a delegate e.g.;

```
var orderedCountries = countries
                            .GroupBy(c => c.Name)
                                .OrderByDescending(c => GetPop(c, year))
                                    .SelectMany(c=>c)  
                                        .ToList();

Func<IGrouping<string, Country>, int, long> GetPop = 
                                    ((cntry, yr) => (from c in cntry
                                                     where c.Year == yr
                                                     select c.population).First());
```

Comment: This is good but I'd add `.SelectMany(i=>i)` before the `.ToList()` to make it `List<Country>` rather than `List<IGrouping<String,Country>>`

Comment: And out of interest why `First` rather than `FirstOrDefault` in the second bit of code?

Answer (score 0):

This is quite equivalent to saj's answer, but using query syntax:

```
var y = 2002;

var ordered = 
    from c in countries
    group c by c.Name into g
    select new
    {
        Name = g.Key,
        Population = (
            from x in g
            where x.Year == y
            select x.population).FirstOrDefault()
    } into s
    orderby s.Population descending
    join f in countries
    on s.Name equals f.Name
    select f;
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a similar question asked here:
[Multiple "order by" in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298725/multiple-order-by-in-linq)

Something like this would do the trick in your case. I tested it in VS and it works as expected:

```
var countries order= countries.OrderBy(c => c.Year).ThenBy(n => n.population);
```

Comment: This isn't what is required. It is not multiple ordering by, but grouping, then ordering.