# How to remove repeatable items in linq query

Tags: c#

```
listOrders.DataSource = (from sp in dbdata.Specifications
                         join ord in dbdata.Orders on sp.O_id equals ord.O_id
                         join prd in dbdata.Products on ord.O_id equals prd.O_ID
                         where sp.Approve == "Yes" && 
                         sp.Awailable_BOM == "Yes" && 
                         prd.Hours_prd == null
                         orderby sp.O_id descending
                         select sp.O_id).Distinct();
```

in here I am tring to get desceding values. But it always gets ascending values. if I remove "Distinct()" it works properly but after adding "Distinct()" this problem occurs.

Comment: you can check this [**`link`**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/298725/1577396)

Comment: I am no pro in linq but did you try `orderby` after `distinct`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
listOrders.DataSource = (from sp in dbdata.Specifications
                         join ord in dbdata.Orders on sp.O_id equals ord.O_id
                         join prd in dbdata.Products on ord.O_id equals prd.O_ID
                         where sp.Approve == "Yes" && 
                         sp.Awailable_BOM == "Yes" && 
                         prd.Hours_prd == null
                         select sp.O_id).Distinct().OrderByDescending();
```

Comment: Inside the OrderByDescending shouldn't it be `x => x.O_id`?

Comment: 0_id is what is being ordered, note the `select`.