# LINQ Multiple order by when not using lambda expressions

Tags: c#, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple “order by” in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298725/multiple-order-by-in-linq)

I want to order some dataset by some field AND THEN some other field.

Using lambda expressions this would be easy (OrderBy.ThenBy), but how to do it when I have a syntax like this:

```
 int maxQueries = int.MaxValue;
        // finds the most search for queries
        var ordered = from p in searchLogs
        where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.SearchQuery)
        group p by new 
        { 
           SearchQuery = p.SearchQuery
        } 
        into pgroup
        let count = pgroup.Count()
        orderby count descending
        select new 
        { 
            Count = count, 
            SearchQuery = pgroup.Key.SearchQuery
        };
```

I can't seem to find a way which works after the decending keyword (like orderby count descending then searchquery)..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put a comma after `descending` and specify the next thing to sort by (optionally adding `descending`) and so on

Answer (score 0):

Just to add some code to **mlorbetske** answer, if you have Customer class like this:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Name;
    public DateTime MemberSince;
}
```

You could then perform an ordering like this:

```
var q = from c in Customers
        orderby c.MemberSince.Date descending, c.Name
        select c;
```