# Sorting data in ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-8, windows-8.1

I have a ListView in my XAML:

```
<ListView Margin="10" Name="lvDataBinding"></ListView>
```

In the code I have User class:

```C#
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public override string ToString
    {
        return this.Name + ", " + this.Age + " years old";
    }
}
```

and code that binds the collection of Users to ListView:

```C#
List<User> items = new List<User>();
items.Add(new User() { Name = "John Doe", Age = 42 });
items.Add(new User() { Name = "Jane Doe", Age = 39 });
items.Add(new User() { Name = "Sammy Doe", Age = 13 });
items.Add(new User() { Name = "Any Dam", Age = 90 });
lvDataBinding.ItemsSource = items;
```

Now I want to sort the data in ListView by User.Name or User.Age. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>You can try by adding a `SortDescription` object to the [`CollectionView.SortDescriptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.sortdescriptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property. For example to sort data in the `ListView` by `User.Age` :</s>

```cs
CollectionView view = 
    (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lvDataBinding.ItemsSource);
view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Age", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```

I was about to suggest using `CollectionView.SortDescriptions` before realizing that [it isn't supported in WinRT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956999/filtering-and-sorting-of-an-observablecollection-in-listview-binding). Possible workaround is by reassigning `ItemsSource` to the new ordered collection. For example to sort by `User.Age` :

```
var source = (List<User>)lvDataBinding.ItemsSource;
lvDataBinding.ItemsSource = source.OrderBy(o => o.Age);
```