# How to display data from database to ListView in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, listview, service-reference

I'm trying to display data from my Entitity Framework database to my ListView in my WPF C# application.

I'm using WCF app as my host, where I keep my methods for displaying data, adding data, etc., and I have WPF app as my client, where I use the code to display data from database to my ListView.

**This is my code**

```
ServiceReference1.ImojWCFServiceClient client = new ServiceReference1.ImojWCFServiceClient();
listView1.Items.Clear();
var userList = client.getUsers();
foreach (var user in userList)
{
   ListViewItem listOfUsers;
   string[] list = new string[3];
   list[0] = user.UserID.ToString();
   list[1] = user.Name;
   list[2] = user.LastName;
   listOfUsers = new ListViewItem(list);
   listView1.Items.Add(listOfUsers);
}
```

**This is the error that I get**
[image]

Can somebody help me fix this code?

**Any help is appreciated!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your `getUsers` method returns a list, array, or similar, you could simply set the ItemsSource of the ListView to `userList`. For example:

```
ServiceReference1.ImojWCFServiceClient client = new ServiceReference1.ImojWCFServiceClient();
listView1.Items.Clear();
var userList = client.getUsers();
listView1.ItemsSource = userList;
```

If that doesn't work, convert userList to an ObservableCollection before setting the ItemsSource

Your Xaml might look like this...

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding UserID}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Last Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 1):

[ListViewItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listviewitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't have a constructor that takes one argument.  So `listOfUsers = new ListViewItem(list);` isn't going to work.

Try an approach [like this](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-data-binding-item-template/):

```
var items = new List<User>();
items.Add(new User() { Name = "John Doe", Age = 42 });
items.Add(new User() { Name = "Jane Doe", Age = 39 });
items.Add(new User() { Name = "Sammy Doe", Age = 13 });
myListView.ItemsSource = items;
```

Comment: It's just an example.  You have to substitute your own use case.  It's not copy/paste code.

Comment: Actually it is copy and paste code from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25862244/sorting-data-in-listview

Comment: @startoftext: That's not what I meant by copy/paste code.  By copy/paste code, I mean trying to cobble together a program by copy/pasting code snippets from the Internet.  *Real programmers actually write code that meets their specific needs!*