# Change binding at runtime to a particular element of a list based off property of the list item

Tags: c#, linq, mvvm, data-binding, windows-runtime

[image: Sample Program]

Say I have a list of Categories (A, B, C, D...) as well as a list of Items which have as a member a list of Details about themselves.

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Details> ItemDetails { get; set; }
}

public class Details
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public int Value1 { get; set; }
    public int Value2 { get; set; }
    public int Value3 { get; set; }
}
```

What I would like to do is to be able to display information about the Item based on which Category is selected in the listview, so if the user selects B then the listview on the right will have in its datatemplate all of the information about that category.  I know how to hardcode it to display a particular item in the list.

```
    <ListView x:Name="CategoriesListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}"/>

    <ListView x:Name="ItemsListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemDetails[0].Value1}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

but what I want is something more like

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemDetails.Find(i => i == **SelectedItem of CategoriesListView**).Value1}"/>
```

The data context to my page looks like.

```
public class MyDataContext
{
    public List<string> Categories { get; set; }

    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

So I want to be able to select a category on the left, and then have the Items on the right ONLY display information from their child Details members where those Details match the category selected.

Comment: I see that there is an implementation of sorted collection view (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/527686/A-WinRT-CollectionView-class-with-Filtering-and-So) which I might try, but I'm making an effort to keep code for which I can't find the license to at a minimum

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if understand your question exactly, but it seems like you want one listview's itemssource to be fed off of another listview's selection.  Is that correct?

If so, this should do the trick (give your classes above):

```
<ListView x:Name="ItemsListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>

<ListView x:Name="CategoriesListView"  ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=ItemsListView, Path=SelectedItem.ItemDetails}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:Details, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Category}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value1}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value2}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value3}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**EDIT:**

To filter one collection from another, I would use the ICollectionView, as demonstrated in the below vm. The key to making it work is setting 'IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem' to true in the xaml.

Hopefully something similar to this will get you rolling.

Here's the updated vm:

```
internal class MainWindowViewModel
{
    private ICollectionView _categories;
    private ICollectionView _itemsWrapper;

    List<Item> _items => new List<Item>()
    {
        new Item()
        {
            Name = "First", ItemDetails = new List<Details>()
            {
                new Details() {Category = "A", Value1 = 1, Value2 = 2, Value3 = 3},
                new Details() {Category = "b", Value1 = 10, Value2 = 203, Value3 = 30},
                new Details() {Category = "c", Value1 = 100, Value2 = 200, Value3 = 300},
            }
        },
                    new Item()
        {
            Name = "Second", ItemDetails = new List<Details>()
            {
                new Details() {Category = "d", Value1 = 1, Value2 = 2, Value3 = 3},
                new Details() {Category = "e", Value1 = 10, Value2 = 203, Value3 = 30},
                new Details() {Category = "f", Value1 = 100, Value2 = 200, Value3 = 300},
            }
        }
    };

    public ICollectionView Categories
    {
        get
        {
            if (_categories == null)
            {
                _categories = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(new ObservableCollection<string>() {"A", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"});
                _categories.CurrentChanged += (s, e) => Items.Refresh();
            }
            return _categories;
        }
    }

    public ICollectionView Items
    {
        get
        {
            if (_itemsWrapper == null)
            {
                _itemsWrapper = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_items);
                _itemsWrapper.Filter = sel =>
                {
                    var item = sel as Item;
                    var toMatch = Categories.CurrentItem.ToString();
                    return item.ItemDetails.Any(i => i.Category == toMatch);
                };
            }
            return _itemsWrapper;
        }
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Details> ItemDetails { get; set; }
}

public class Details
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public int Value1 { get; set; }
    public int Value2 { get; set; }
    public int Value3 { get; set; }
}
```

...and the updated xaml:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <ListView x:Name="ItemsListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:Item, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <ListView x:Name="CategoriesListView"  ItemsSource="{Binding ItemDetails}">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:Details, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Category}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value1}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value2}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value3}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                    </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: I'll try to clarify it, the problem is that I only want to display the Details which match the category, and the first listview isn't a list of items, but a list of the categories

Comment: From what I can tell (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956999/filtering-and-sorting-of-an-observablecollection-in-listview-binding) the WinRT ICollectionView doesn't support filters or sorting, and when I tried to use what you suggested it can't find those functions.
If at all possible I'd have preferred to do this without having to have the View set a member of the ViewModel or Model and use LINQ or something to manipulate a copy of the underlying collection

Comment: You're right, in WinRT (or UWP for that matter) the ICollectionView interface does not yet support filtering.  In that case, you're gonna have to manually wire in some filtering logic.

The following link may help you, too, to get a proper ListcollectionView in WinRT:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/527686/A-WinRT-CollectionView-class-with-Filtering-and-So