# Generate missing list values in c# list using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list that contains the following class

```
    public class File
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public int Year{get;set;}
    public decimal Amount{get;set;}

}
```

My list could contain i.e List

```
Name="File 1" Year=2011 Amount=200
Name="File 2" Year=2012 Amount=400
Name="File 3" Year 2013 Amount=500
```

I would like the above list to be transform to contain the following values

```
Name="File 1" Year=2011 Amount=200
Name="File 1" Year=2012 Amount=0
Name="File 1" Year 2013 Amount=0
Name="File 2" Year=2011 Amount=400
Name="File 2" Year=2012 Amount=0
Name="File 2" Year 2013 Amount=0
Name="File 3" Year 2011 Amount=0
Name="File 3" Year=2012 Amount=0
Name="File 3" Year 2013 Amount=500
```

Note that the other items with an amount of 0 are automatically generated for the missing years

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach(var name in files.Select(x => x.Name).Distinct())
foreach(var year in files.Select(x => x.Year).Distinct())
{
    var amount = (from file in files
                  where file.Name == name
                     && file.Year == year
                  select (decimal?)file.Amount).SingleOrDefault() ?? 0M;
    Console.WriteLine("Name={0}, Year={1}, Amount={2}",
                  name, year, amount);
}
```

Obviously it could be optimized - especially as a lookup for the amount via a dictionary; maybe:

```
var amounts = files.ToDictionary(
        file => new {file.Name,file.Year}, file => file.Amount);

foreach(var name in files.Select(file => file.Name).Distinct())
foreach(var year in files.Select(file => file.Year).Distinct())
{
    decimal amount;
    if(!amounts.TryGetValue(new {file.Name,file.Year}, out amount) amount = 0M;
    Console.WriteLine("Name={0}, Year={1}, Amount={2}",
                  name, year, amount);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the default value, you can add a constructor :

```
public class File
{
    public File() { this.Amout = 0; }

    public string Name{get;set;}
    public int Year{get;set;}
    public decimal Amount{get;set;}
}
```

For the OrderBy, you can look on [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298725/multiple-order-by-in-linq)