# Group by C# Concat?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

I need to have endResult to be in descending order by ID and am not sure how that works with c# Linq.  Any help would be great.

```
private void textBox6_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataClasses3DataContext db = new DataClasses3DataContext();

    int matchedAdd = (from c in db.GetTable<prop>()
                      where c.streetNum.Contains(textBox1.Text) && c.Direction.Contains(textBox2.Text) && c.street.Contains(textBox4.Text) && c.SUFF.Contains(textBox6.Text)
                      select c.ID).Single();

    var before = (from c in db.GetTable<prop>()
                  where c.ID < matchedAdd
                  orderby c.PARCEL descending
                  select c).Take(6);

    var after = (from c in db.GetTable<prop>()
                 where c.ID > matchedAdd
                 orderby c.PARCEL
                 select c).Take(6);

    var endResult = after.Concat(before);

    dgvBRT.DataSource = endResult;

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298725/multiple-order-by-in-linq

Comment: Sounds like you didn't even try to solve this problem.  Did you look around at *all* as to how to order a sequence using LINQ?

Comment: @Servy yep I didn't bother to do anything.  I just came here and posted without even the slightest attempt <sarcasm off> .

Comment: @korrowan Where did you look?  What did you try?  What happened as a result of those attempts?  Did you get errors, were they compile time or runtime, did you get incorrect outputs, etc?  There are *thousands* of tutorials on this subject, so there is a *lot* of information out there that demonstrates *exactly* how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dgvBRT.DataSource = endResult.OrderByDescending(x => x.ID);
```

...there's not much else to say.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I wasn't sure where to put the orderby..thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This may helps:

```
after.Concat(befor).OrderByDescending(i => i.ID);
```