# LINQ Queries with dynamic Order By - more than one field

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have a collection with name,date,category as parameters. I want to sort the list based on the input order of the three which changes dynamically. 
For ex: in one case i have to sort on the order date,name, category respectively.
in another case the order is name, date and category.So i can have all the permutation and combinations. Can someone help me with a generic way to implement it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple "order by" in LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298725/multiple-order-by-in-linq)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby-on-ienumerablet

Comment: LINQ provides this out of the box using the ThenBy function, no need to use Dynamic Linq or anything

Comment: i know that LinQ has orderby and thenby function. But the problem here is since the order of fields is dynamic, how do i pass the field and arrange them accordingly ?

Answer (score 1):

LINQ already allows you to sort using multiple fields by adding the [Queryable.ThenBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.thenby.aspx), [QueryableThenByDescending](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.thenbydescending.aspx), [Enumerable.ThenBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534743.aspx) or [Enumerable.ThenByDescending](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.thenbydescending.aspx) functions after OrderBy.

Check [Multiple “order by” in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298725/multiple-order-by-in-linq) for a similar question and the discussion.

As an aside, you can convert an Enumerable to a Queryable simply calling [AsQueryable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353734.aspx) on it, if you need a rare method that is not provided by Enumerable.

Comment: i know that LinQ has orderby and thenby function. But the problem here is since the order of fields is dynamic, how do i pass the field and arrange them accordingly ?

Comment: You don't need to *pass* anything, just call ThenBy with the appropriate lambda depending on the field you want to order by. Even a simple switch statement is OK. Or, you can create an array/list with the lambdas you want to order by and apply them one by one. A lambda is just another type of variable after all

Comment: i am not sure if you ve understood me rightly or i did not get it ...can you gimme the sample code ?                                   According to yoursolution for the first field i need to give orderby. and for the rest its thenby? so how do make it possible dynamically ?

Answer (score 0):

I also found here something that he might like: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27834/Generic-List-Sort-Function <-- hope it helps, it sorts by any input property. The property is taken through reflection.

Comment: the method is implemented in List and not IQueryable. So can only be used after a .ToList() or in other words after the data has been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example

```
// Just to get IOrderedEnumerable from the collection
// And set the default order
var orderedItems = context.Items.OrderBy(i => i.Name);

var orderByString = txtOrderBy.Text.ToLower();
switch(orderByString)
{
    case "category":
        orderedItems = orderedItems.OrderBy(i => i.Category);
        break;
    case "date":
        orderedItems = orderedItems.OrderBy(i => i.Date);
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: This does NOT order by a set of fields, only the last OrderBy field counts.