# Merge results of 2 LINQ To SQL queries and keep their ordering

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, concatenation

I need to append the results of one LINQ To SQL query to another on the database server side without reordering rows.

I need all errored orders first, then the pending orders.

```
var error = database.Orders.
    Where(o => o.Status == XOrderStatus.Error).
    OrderByDescending(o => o.Id);
var pending = database.Orders.
    Where(o => o.Status == XOrderStatus.PendingReview).
    OrderByDescending(o => o.Id);
    var r = error.OrderedUnion(pending);
```

How I can implement the `OrderedUnion()` method? `Concat`, `Union` and `Distinct` methods completely eliminate `OrderByDescending` call (by design).

I know it is possible to do with two `ToArray()` calls, but I am interested having this done at the database level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can concatente them together and then order by a column that seperates the order groups. so for instance in an SQL Query you would do this:

`ORDER BY XOrderStatus, Id`

and that would order by ID but with the two OrderStatuses grouped.

I don't know linq to sql (sorry!) but a quick Google mentioned this may work:

`.Orderby(o => o.XOrderStatus).ThenBy(o => o.Id)`

Original Source:

[Multiple "order by" in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298725/multiple-order-by-in-linq)

Comment: Well, good answer. It gives an idea. I updated my question with solution based on your 'grouping' approach.

Comment: Just use a constant (`select new { OrderPrefix = 1, OtherFields... }`).

Answer (score 0):

I found much better solution:

```
var all = database.Orders.
    Where(o =>
        o.Status == XOrderStatus.Error ||
        o.Status == XOrderStatus.PendingReview).
    OrderBy(o => o.Status == XOrderStatus.Error ? 0 : 1).
    ThenByDescending(o => o.Id).
    ToArray();
```