# c# databable how to sort this one

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

This is my code

```
var result = (from row in InBoundtable.AsEnumerable()
    where campains.Contains(row.Field<string>("Campaign"))
    group row by new
    {
      Date = row.Field<string>("Date"),
      Slice = row.Field<string>("Slice")
    } into grp
    select new
    {
      SL = grp.Sum((r) => Double.Parse(r["Inb.ServiceLevel"].ToString())) / grp.Count(),
      Date = ((DateTime.Parse(grp.Key.Date.ToString() + " " + grp.Key.Slice.ToString().Split('-')[0])) - epoch).TotalMilliseconds
    }).ToList();
```

how can I sort the `result` according to the `Date` column? from past to current

for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how can I sort the result according to the Date column? from past to
>   current

Use [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534966(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
var result = (from row in InBoundtable.AsEnumerable()
              where campains.Contains(row.Field<string>("Campaign"))
              group row by new
              {
                  Date = row.Field<string>("Date"),
                  Slice = row.Field<string>("Slice")
              } into grp
              select new
              {
                  SL = grp.Sum((r) => Double.Parse(r["Inb.ServiceLevel"].ToString())) / grp.Count(),
                  Date = ((DateTime.Parse(grp.Key.Date.ToString() + " " + grp.Key.Slice.ToString().Split('-')[0])) - epoch).TotalMilliseconds
              })
              .OrderBy(r=> r.Date) //HERE
              .ToList();
```

Comment: that will sort from past to current or from current to past please? I want if I did this: `result[0]` to have `2012` and `result[100]` to have `2014`. ofc I am asking about the idea not the current syntax of `result`

Comment: `OrderBy` will sort in Ascending order, so it will be from past to current. If you want order in descending order *(current to last past date)* then use `OrderByDescending`

Comment: can I order by `date` and **after finishing ordering by date** then order by `Slice` please?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli, sure you can do that, First use `OrderBy(r=> r.Date)` and for second ordering use `ThenBy(r=> r.Slice)`, But you are not selecting Slice, in your anonymous type. Thus it will not be available, You may select that in your last select statement and then you can apply, `ThenBy` similarly if you want the second order to be in descending order then use `ThenByDescending`

Comment: You may also see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298725/multiple-order-by-in-linq

Comment: there is no `Slice` in `r=>r.Slice`. I think that I have to add it to the `select` but I don't know how, please help me in this last thing ? +1 and accepted answer

Comment: In the last `select new`, specify `Slice` from previous `grp`

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli, yes that should do it.

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli, Glad to be a help