# Ordering a List by the highest value of two properties

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list like the following one:

```
|Name|Val. Date 1| Val. Date 2|
|PA  |        200|         200|
|PB  |          0|         300|
|PC  |        200|           0|
|PD  |        150|         150|
```

Ordering the list by Val. Date1 will give me something like: PA, PC, PD and PB. and something similar if I do it for Val. Date 2.

But what I really need to do, is to order it by the highest value recorded in Date 1 or Date 2, what results in something like this: PB, PA, PC and PD.

How can I solve this matter?

Comment: What is the structure of `List<T>`

Comment: Why not create a new propety with max(Val1,Val2) value , and order by this value ?

Comment: What have you tried till now? Where are you stuck? Improve your question by posting your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `Math.Max()` to get the maximum value and then order by it:

```
 list.OrderByDescending(x => Math.Max(x.Date1, x.Date2));
```

Comment: if you add a `ThenByDescending` with the sum of both values it should work in the border-cases ;9

Comment: @CarstenKönig: It cannot be deduced from the question that this is the desired behavior. OP asks for ordering by the highest value of two properties, and this solution provides that.

Comment: OP wants the lists to be order by having using the heighest of the 2 numbers of the same index number so it uses the `300` and not the `0` by  `PC`. It should compare the 2 numbers with the same index number and see what one the highest is, and then order the lists with only using the highest numbers

Comment: The provided answer works as I wanted. I knew there was a away to do it with linq but I didn't remember to use the Math class :)

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using a list, you can do an inline sort of the list using [`List.Sort(Comparison<T>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
list.Sort((lhs, rhs) => 
(
    Math.Max(lhs.Val.Date1, lhs.Val.Date2) - 
    Math.Max(rhs.Val.Date1, rhs.Val.Date2)
));
```

If you are assigning the results of the Linq solution back to a list using `.ToList()`, then doing an in-place sort instead will be much more efficient with one important caveat:

`List.Sort()` is NOT a stable sort, so that it doesn't preserve the ordering of equal values. The Linq `OrderBy`, however, is a stable sort.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use something like:

```
var sortedList = ListOfData.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Val1).ThenByDescending(x=>x.Val2);
```

See:
[Multiple “order by” in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298725/multiple-order-by-in-linq)
[Ordering data in LINQ queries by more than one column](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/231162/Ordering-data-in-LINQ-Queries-by-more-than-one-col)
[Multiple Field Sorting by Field Names Using Linq](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/280952/Multiple-Column-Sorting-by-Field-Names-Using-Linq)