# Entity Framework Sorting According to 2 columns at the same time

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I stucked at somewhere while developing our system. I have 2 different datetime columns DateModified and DateCreated. I want to sort my data according to those 2 columns at the same time. Like;

Id Name   DateCreated         DateModified
--------------------------------------------------------
1  Ali         2015-01-01              2015-02-02
2  Veli               2015-01-02              2015-02-03
3  Mehmed             2015-02-01              2015-02-05
4  Ahmed              2015-02-04              null

When I want to make a descending order by for those data, it should give me the result of

3 Mehmed
4 Ahmed
2 Veli
1 Ali

So... What is the way of doing that? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple "order by" in LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298725/multiple-order-by-in-linq)

Answer (score 4):

From what I understand you want the result to be sorted by both dates as a single property, not using ThenBy right?

Not a LINQ expert but I think this should work:

```
var Result = Items.OrderBy(x=> x.DateModified==null ? x.DateCreated : x.DateModified);
```

EDIT:

This goes on the assumption that the modify date is always after the creation date. In an general case it would look like this:

```
var Result = Items.OrderBy(x=> x.A >= x.B ? x.A : x.B);
```

Comment: Or `x.DateModified ?? x.DateCreated`

Answer (score 1):

use `OrderBy` and `ThenBy`

```
var Result = Items.OrderBy(x => x.DateModified).ThenBy(x => x.DateCreated);
```

Answer (score 0):

If Ahmed is second, then you can use DateCreated instead of null:
`Items.OrderBy(a => a.DateModified != default(DateTime?) a.DateModified: a.DateCreated);`