# How to order a list alphabetically depending on another list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a page that displays Companies, they all are appart of groups. Here is the display of the page: [image]

The first column contains the names of the groupes and the second of the companies.

What I want to achieve is to order the list first by Group name alphabetically (which has been done) and THEN order the items that are appart of one group alphabetically between each other.

I order the Groups like such :

```
 return View(_service.List().OrderBy(o => o.GroupId).ToList());
```

Where `_service.List()` gives the list of Groups.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple "order by" in LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298725/multiple-order-by-in-linq)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ThenBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.linq.enumerable.thenby(v=vs.100).aspx) method:

```
var model = _service.List()
    .OrderBy(o => o.GroupId)
    .ThenBy(x => x.Company)
    .ToList()
return View(model);
```

Comment: Lovely ! But can I even go crazy and do it twice? `_service.List()
    .OrderBy(o => o.GroupId)
    .ThenBy(x => x.Company).ThenBy(z => z.Name)
    .ToList()` because it doesn't seem to let me do it.
EDIT: Of course I can, my error came from something else. Thank you !