# Linq orderby is ignored

Tags: c#, linq

Hello I'm not clear why my linq statement `orderby` is not working as expected.

```
  var q = from DirectoryInfo subDirectory
          in item.GetDirectories()
          orderby (item.Name == "TableDefinition" ? 1 : 2), item.Name
          select subDirectory;
  foreach (DirectoryInfo subDirectory in q)
  {
    Execute(subDirectory);
  }
```

I want the items sorted first by seeing if the name is "TableDefinition" or not, then secondly just by name.

It appears that it's just sorting by name only, in alpha order ascending.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298725/multiple-order-by-in-linq . This may be the solution.

Comment: you need custom IComparer here i guess

Comment: @hvd, yes, the subdirectory is exactly named "TableDefinition"

Comment: @hvd Correct you are. As a debugging attempt I might try the first part of the query (from x in y), cache it, then execute the LINQ style of Orderby(...).ThenBy(...).

It *shouldn't* change the outcome, but I would be tempted to try it anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `subDirectory` in place of `item`

```
var q = from DirectoryInfo subDirectory
        in item.GetDirectories()
        orderby (subDirectory.Name == "TableDefinition" ? 1 : 2), subDirectory.Name
        select subDirectory;
foreach (DirectoryInfo subDirectory in q)
{
    Execute(subDirectory);
}
```

Comment: Now I'm embarrassed.

Comment: @toddmo That's why you should always use Lambda expressions

Comment: `var q = item.GetDirectories().OrderBy(x=> x.Name == "TableDefinition" ? 1 : 2).ThenBy(x=> x.Name)`