# how to order a list by Property Value using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I need to order the items that are defined in a list called preferences.

```
List<String> preferences = new List<String> { "first","second","third" };
IEnumerable<mylist> orderedData = mylist.OrderBy(item => preferences.IndexOf(item));
```

*ordereddata* output should be

```
first
second
third... //Remaining property values comes here
```

please give the suggestion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple "order by" in LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298725/multiple-order-by-in-linq)

Answer (score 0):

Look for an index if available in preference list else use `int.MaxValue` to keep it at the end.

```
List<String> preferences = new List<String> { "first","second","third" };
IEnumerable<MyList> orderedData = mylist.OrderBy(item => 
                                         {
                                              var index = preferences.IndexOf(item);   // use property if item is an object.
                                              return index>=0 ? index: int.MaxValue;
                                         });
```

Check this [`example`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qUR0jM)

Answer (score 0):

```
        List<string> lst = new List<string>() { "b", "d", "f" };
        List<string> main = new List<string>() { "a", "g", "e" };
        main = main.OrderByDescending(O => O.ToString()).ToList();
        lst.Reverse();
        main.AddRange(lst);
        main.Reverse();

        foreach (var item in main)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
```