# Order a list of lists in C# using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, list, sorting

There is a list of polygons `List<Polygon> Polygons` defined by these classes.

How can I order that list, so that the polygon are ordered first by the **X** property of their Points and then by the **Y** property of their Points in an ascending order.

```
public class Polygon
{
    public List<Point2D> Points;
}

public class Point2D
{
    public double X;
    public double Y;
}
```

**Update:** For example consider these polygons:

```
(A) (0, 0) -> (5, 1) -> (5, -3) -> (0, -3) -> (0, 0)
(B) (0, -10) -> (5, -9) -> (5, -13) -> (0, -13) -> (0, -10)
(C) (10, 0) -> (15, 1) -> (15, -3) -> (10, -3) -> (10, 0)
```

the sorted output:

```
(A) (0, -10) -> (5, -9) -> (5, -13) -> (0, -13) -> (0, -10)
(B) (0, 0) -> (5, 1) -> (5, -3) -> (0, -3) -> (0, 0)
(C) (10, 0) -> (15, 1) -> (15, -3) -> (10, -3) -> (10, 0)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298725/multiple-order-by-in-linq

Comment: what if there are intersections of polygons

Comment: Thanks @user189756, but my question seems a bit different as I understand it.

Comment: @user853710 There are no intersections between the polygons.

Comment: So you don't wont to order the outer list, but just order the points inside each Polygon?

Comment: No, I want to order the polygons based on their points. I want to keep the polygons unchanged, just make a new list of polygons that are sorted from left to right and top to bottom.

Comment: You said "first by the X property of their Points", but "their points" has no X property. Each point has a property named X, but a `List<Point>` hasn't.

Comment: What makes one polygon come before another? The smallest X for that polygon against the smallest X for the other one? And then if these are equal, then compare the smallest Y for polygon1 with the smallest Y for polygon2?

Comment: What if you add "D: (0, 0) -> (5, 1) -> (4, -3) -> (0, -3) -> (0, 0)" and "E: (100, 100) -> (0, 0) -> (0, 0) -> (0, -3) -> (0, 0)", where would they get sorted?

Comment: Why is `(0, 0)` smaller than `(0, -10)`?

Comment: have a look at my solution. Should do the trick

Comment: @user853710 Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to order the polygons based on the smallest X value of their points, and if these are equal, then based on the smallest Y value of their points.

Here is how you can do it with LINQ:

```
var result =
    Polygons
    //Order by smallest X
    .OrderBy(pl => pl.Points.Min(pn => pn.X)) 
    //Then by smallest Y
    .ThenBy(pl => pl.Points.Min(pn => pn.Y))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I don't think this is what he does, because otherwise polygon B would end up earlier than polygon C (B and C are names in the original list; OP does not seem to keep them in the sorted list). It looks like you spotted that, too (I mean your comment on the question).

Comment: This seems to be right answer. I made a mistake preparing the example. But the whole idea is correct.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, for Y, I changed it from `Min` to `Max` to make it work for the example OP provided. If OP is mistaken, he can change it back from `Max` to `Min`.

Comment: @YacoubMassad I did. Thanks. I will try this now.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add other properties to the polygon class

```
public class Polygon
{
    public List<Point2D> Points;

    public Point2D MinPoint;
}
```

This part will depend on the distibution of you points and adept the algorith fitting to you needs.
then you need to find the min point of a polygon One representative of the polygon. Might be the center, bottomleft point or center of a convex hull. One representative. (this might be a bit wrong but you need to play with it a bit). This depend on the various scenarios

```
foreach(var poly in Polygons)
{
    int minx = poly.Points.Min(p=>p.X);
    int minY = poly.Points.Where(p=>p.X==minX).Min(p=>p.Y);
    poly.MinPoint = poly.Points.FirstOrDefault(p=>p.X==minX && p.Y==minY)
}
```

Then you can sort it.

```
var sortedPolygons = polygons.OrderBy(p=>p.MinPoint.X).ThenBy(p=>p.MinPoint.Y);
```

Comment: you can also put the minpoint part into the polygon class itself

Comment: It would also be suggested to implement in Point2D the IComparable inteface, the you can add the comparisson of two point directly to the method and use standard sorting mechanisms. The same should be applied to the polygon as well. This is actually the "by the book" solution

Comment: OrderBy needs IComparer, not IComparable

Answer (score 0):

You can write a Comparer class for comparing the Points inside a polygon and use that to order the polygons.

```
class PointsComparer : IComparer<List<Point2D>>
{
    public int Compare(List<Point2D> left, List<Point2D> right)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < left.Count && i < right.Count; i++) {
            int c = left[i].X.CompareTo(right[i].X);
            if (c != 0) return c;
            c = left[i].Y.CompareTo(right[i].Y);
            if (c != 0) return c;
        }
        return left.Count.CompareTo(right.Count);
    }
}


polygons.OrderBy(poly => poly.Points, new PointsComparer());
```

Side note: you may want to turn those fields into properties.