# Operator && cannot be applied to operands of type decimal and decimal

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, xamarin.android

I would like to get the last 5 values of performance and availability time. To get that I have tried multiple ways, but unfortunately without succes.

I have tried this:

```
var completeTransactions2 = temp4
                        .Where(x => x.GroupidAvai == x.GroupidPerf && x.KeyTimeAvai == x.KeyTimePerf)
                        .GroupBy(x => x.GroupidAvai)
                        .Select(group => group.OrderByDescending(record => (record.KeyTimeAvai) && (record.KeyTimePerf)).Take(5));
```

But then I get an error: *Operator && cannot be applied to operands of type decimal and decimal.*

With that information I have tried something but with result that only one perfTime is being taking the last 5 values and reverse them. Availability is only have one avaitime. This is the query:

```
var orderedTemp72 = temp4
                        .Where(x => x.GroupidAvai == x.GroupidPerf)
                        .GroupBy(x => new { x.GroupidAvai, x.GroupidPerf })
                        .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(record => record.KeyTimeAvai)
                        .ThenByDescending(record => record.KeyTimePerf).Take(5).Reverse());
```

I hope that someone can put me in the right direction for how solving this. If there are question, please don't hesitate to ask.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Try addin parenthesis around the two == expressions.

Comment: It's not quite clear what are you trying to achieve. If you are filtering the items with `x.GroupidAvai == x.GroupidPerf`, then why you group by `x.GroupidAvai, x.GroupidPerf`. Either filter is incorrect or group by contains redundant fields. Providing sample input data and desired output will help us understanding the goal in order to help you.

Comment: @IvanStoev You are correct. There is some double data, but for now I need that to achieve my end goal here. Sorry for the confusion, but you all helped me with solving this obstacle :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for responding/helping me. Really appreciated :)
With all your answers I came to the following solution that I can use.

```
var completeTransactions = temp
                    .Where(x => x.GroupidAvai == x.GroupidPerf && x.KeyTimeAvai == x.KeyTimePerf)
                    .GroupBy(x => x.GroupidAvai)
                        .Select(group => group.OrderByDescending(record => record.KeyTimeAvai).Reverse().Take(5).OrderByDescending(record => record.KeyTimePerf).Reverse().Take(5));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is your orderbyDescending statement.

Try something like

```
var completeTransactions2 = temp4
                    .Where(x => x.GroupidAvai == x.GroupidPerf && x.KeyTimeAvai == x.KeyTimePerf)
                    .GroupBy(x => x.GroupidAvai)
                    .Select(group => group.OrderByDescending(record => record.KeyTimeAvai).ThenBy(x => record.KeyTimePerf)).Take(5));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this syntax by Doing `OrderByDescending` and `ThenByDescending`

```
var completeTransactions2 = temp4
                    .Where(x => x.GroupidAvai == x.GroupidPerf && x.KeyTimeAvai == x.KeyTimePerf)
                    .GroupBy(x => x.GroupidAvai)
                    .Select(gro => gro.OrderByDescending(r => r.KeyTimeAvai).ThenByDescending(r => r.KeyTimePerf).Take(5));
```

**OR** Doing `OrderByDescending` and `ThenBy`

```
var completeTransactions2 = temp4
                        .Where(x => x.GroupidAvai == x.GroupidPerf && x.KeyTimeAvai == x.KeyTimePerf)
                        .GroupBy(x => x.GroupidAvai)
                        .Select(gro => gro.OrderByDescending(r => r.KeyTimeAvai).ThenBy(r => r.KeyTimePerf).Take(5));
```

Take a look [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298725/multiple-order-by-in-linq)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the five greatest of KeyTimeAvai or KeyTimePerf

```
OrderByDescending(x => x.KeyTimeAvai >= x.KeyTimePerf 
                       ? x.KeyTimeAvai 
                       : x.KeyTimePerf).Take(5);
```

If you need the five greatest KeyTimeAvai and five greatest KeyTimePerf (so 10 results), I would do something like that.

```
var groupedTransactions=  temp4
                          .Where(x => x.GroupidAvai == x.GroupidPerf &&
                                      x.KeyTimeAvai == x.KeyTimePerf)
                          .GroupBy(x => x.GroupidAvai);



var greatestByAvai = groupedTransactions
                     .Select(group => group.OrderByDescending(record => record.KeyTimeAvai)
                     .Take(5);
var greatestByPerf = groupedTransactions
                     .Select(group => group.OrderByDescending(record => record.KeyTimePerf)
                     .Take(5);

var allTransactions = greatesByAvai.Concat(greatestByPerf);
```