# C# Order by class type first, then use CompareTo

Tags: c#, linq

I have an abstract class named `Time`, then two subclasses `SingleYear` and `Period`. I could have more subclasses later on.

The `Time` class implements `IComparable`, but the `CompareTo` function is actually implemented in each subclass.

I have a query in linq, like this: `myListOfObjects.OrderBy(o=>o.Time);`

That is working.
However, I'd like to be able to choose whether `SingleYear` or `Period` objects should come first (before the actual `CompareTo`). My implementation of `CompareTo` is correct, however in some cases I need to show first Periods, then Single Years (or vice-versa).

Since I can have more (let's say 5-6) subclasses, how am I able to specify which subclasses should come first, then CompareTo will do it's work afterwards?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you already have a working solution.  Consider adapting the question for Code Review to have your working code reviewed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple "order by" in LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298725/multiple-order-by-in-linq)

Comment: @Servy He has working code that does something else. Everybody who asks a question here has some working code that does something else.

Comment: @EdPlunkett No, he has working code that does exactly what he want.  It doesn't function differently than he needs it to.

Comment: @Servy "how am I able to specify which subclasses should come first" sounds like he's got a sort, but he wants a different sort.

Comment: @EdPlunkett He then follows that up with code to sort classes by their class, and then the time, which is exactly what he wants to do.

Comment: @Servy Oh, you're looking at an old edit. Whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases the point of having classes and subclasses is that we can cast them as a base class (or interface) and no longer have to distinguish between specific types.

If you sort these in a way that is aware of the type and you have five or six types then you're eventually going to end up with this:

```
.OrderBy(o => o is SingleYear)
    .ThenBy(o => o is Period)
    .ThenBy(o => o is SomeOtherClass)
    .ThenBy(o => o is Another)
    .ThenBy(o => o is Whatever)
    .ThenBy(o => o is Etc)
    .ThenBy(o => o.Time);
```

It's not the end of the world but I wouldn't like it. It's better if we don't differentiate between classes in our code (inspecting to see what type they are.) Instead, classes differentiate *themselves* by implementing properties and methods differently.

Does the sort order depend on the length of the period? You could have your classes implement a property that indicates the length of a period - perhaps that's constant for `SingleYear` but calculated for `Period`.

Then you could either implement `IComparable` on each class or provide a separate `IComparer<T>` implementation, like

```
public class TimeComparer : IComparer<Time>
{
    public int Compare(Time t1, Time t2)
    {
        var periodComparison = t1.Duration.CompareTo(t2.Duration);
        return periodComparison != 0 ? periodComparison : t1.Time.CompareTo(t2.Time);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
.OrderBy(o => o is SingleYear).ThenBy(o => o.Time);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would do it:

```
list.OrderBy(t => typeof(t).Name).ThenBy(o => o.Time)
```