# .NET IQueryable OrderBy Aggregated Field

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Is there any way to perform an OrderBy with an aggregated field (string.Join)?

```
var query = <Some IQueryable<T>>;
    
query = query.OrderBy(x => string.Join(",", x.Values.Select(v => v.Name)));
```

I am building dynamic queries and came up a need to order by a column that is agreggated like the above example.

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298725/multiple-order-by-in-linq

Comment: How would you plan to write that in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

You need to first project the aggregated column before you can do OrderBy.

```
    query = query.Select(x=>new {
    Item = x,
    Agg = x => string.Join(",", x.Values.Select(v => v.Name))
    }).OrderBy(a=>a.Agg).Select(a=>a.Item)
```